# What is the main idea and the main problem of Dostoyevsky's Demons?

Tags: russian-language, fyodor-dostoyevsky, theme, demons

What is the main idea and the main problem of Dostoyevsky's novel *Demons*? I have tried to identify one main idea and the main problem of the novel, but in the end nothing came out.

Comment: What makes you think it has one main idea and one main problem?

Comment: If there are two or three main ideas and problems, I would like to know them